# Hide Column Based on Another Column Value Using JSON View Formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online

Using JSON formatting, is it possible to hide a column based on another column value.

Example:
View displays columns A, B, C and D
View is limited to one row
If the value in column D equals Yes, don't display column A.

Edit - SP Online modern site is being used.

Answer (score 0):

If your are not using a modern site, i will advise you to use JSLink

[CSharpCorner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/modify-sharepoint-list-view-using-client-side-rendering-and-jslink/)

Comment: I'll give it a shot and report back.  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below JSON code to format the column A:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "debugMode": true,
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "display": "=if([$ColumnD]=='Yes','none','')"
  }
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: close. I'm wanting to hide the column, not just the value.  my view is filtered to one row.

Comment: So you want to hide the column header too. However, we cannot not only hide only one column header using JSON View Formatting. We could  use "hideColumnHeader": true to hide column headers, but it would hide all column headers. Please read here for more :https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting